# why in spark structured streaming aggregation results are empty rows

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, streaming

In spark structures streaming if inner join and aggregation is used with watermark then getting zero rows as output how to fix it

All batches are empty

The code I'm using:

```scala
val joinedQuery = df1.join(df2, expr("id1=id2 and time1>=time2 and time1<=time2 + interval 10 minutes"), joinType="inner")
val grpQuery = joinedQuery.withWaterMark("time1", "30 seconds").groupBy(window($"time1", "50 seconds").agg(sum(price))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please provide an example of code that you already have? Here is an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about minimal reproducible example that can help you.

Comment: val joinedQuery = df1.join(df2 ,expr(" id1=id2 and time1>=time2 and time1<=time2 + interval 10 minutes"),joinType="inner")
vall grpQuery = joinedQuery.withWaterMark("time1","30 seconds").groupBy(window($"time1","50 seconds").agg(sum(price))